# R: Highlighting multiple items in the same sentence in the data frame

Tags: r, replace, highlight, gsub

I have a table that contains a list of the words I would like to highlight and the text i would like to highlight it in:

```
df <- data_frame(
  tags = list(list("sphinx", "judge", "vow"), list("jackdaws", "sphinx", "love"), list()),
  text = list("Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow", "Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz", 
           "Carved symbols in a mountain hollow on the bank of an inlet irritated an eccentric person.")
) %>%
  mutate(text = as.character(text))
```

I was thinking of doing something like

```
gsub(df$tags[1][[1]][1], paste0('<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">', df$tags[1][[1]][1], '</span>'), df$text[1], ignore.case = TRUE)
```

However I am struggling to figure out how to replace multiple things in the same sentence, if I do a loop for example, it will overwrite itself and I will only get replaced the last word in the list.

Also, I am not entirely sure how to make it work within data frame.

Expected output would be something like

```
df_output <- data_frame(
      tags = list(list("sphinx", "judge", "vow"), list("jackdaws", "sphinx", "love"), list()),
      text = list("<span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">Sphinx</span> of black quartz, <span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">judge</span> my <span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">vow<span>", "<span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">Jackdaws</span> <span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">love</span> my big <span style="background-color: '#FFFF00'">sphinx</span> of quartz", 
               "Carved symbols in a mountain hollow on the bank of an inlet irritated an eccentric person.")
    ) %>%
      mutate(text = as.character(text))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can accept a simplified `tags` object (not a nested list), you could do it iteratively like this. Notice also that I've replaced the first word in `tags` with capital S.

```
tags <- list("Sphinx", "judge", "vow", "jackdaws", "sphinx", "love")
text <- list("Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow", "Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz", 
              "Carved symbols in a mountain hollow on the bank of an inlet irritated an eccentric person.")

for (i in seq_along(tags)) {
  for (j in seq_along(text)) {
    text[[j]] <- gsub(sprintf("(%s)", tags[[i]]),
                      replacement = '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">\\1</span>',
                      x = text[[j]])
  }
}

[[1]]
[1] "<span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">Sphinx</span> of black quartz, <span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">judge</span> my <span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">vow</span>"

[[2]]
[1] "Jackdaws <span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">love</span> my big <span style=\"background-color: #FFFF00\">sphinx</span> of quartz"

[[3]]
[1] "Carved symbols in a mountain hollow on the bank of an inlet irritated an eccentric person."
```